# How to get executable program from tar.xz file

Tags: files, tar

I want to use the program KDE Iso Imagewriter, but it seems to only be available as a tar.xz file. How do I derive an executable file from the tar.xz file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file) I'm aware that the compression format is different, but it is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 2):

This KDE Iso Imagewriter package is distributed in source code form. It is possible to get compilation instructions for Ubuntu by reading [ArchLinux PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=isoimagewriter).

Below is the list of commands for building on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wget xz-utils cmake extra-cmake-modules build-essential gettext libkf5i18n-dev libkf5coreaddons-dev libkf5widgetsaddons-dev libkf5iconthemes-dev libudev-dev libgpgme-dev libgpgmepp-dev libgpg-error-dev pkg-config appstream

cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://download.kde.org/unstable/isoimagewriter/0.8/isoimagewriter-0.8.tar.xz
tar -xf isoimagewriter-0.8.tar.xz
cd isoimagewriter-0.8
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install
```

and then enjoy KDE Iso Imagewriter.